# Using Self method and Respond_to in a controller not working in RUBY

Tags: ruby

In a page managed by Team, I am calling a partial teamember/details.htmls.erb which rely on data loaded by a self method in TeamemberController:

```
def self.get_details(data, current_userID)
  helper_method :current_user
  @team = Team.find_by(id: data)
  current_user = User.find_by(id: current_userID)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
      @team_members = Teamember.where(team_id: @team.id)
    }
    format.html {
      @team_members = Teamember.where(team_id: data)
    }
  end
```

But when I try to refresh the page I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <% @team_members.each do |teamate| %>
    2:   <div class="btn-filter">
    3:     <%= check_box_tag "by_emails[]", email %> <%= User.find_by(email: teamate.email).full_name %>
    4:   </div>
```

While there are definitely some data in @team_members.
is there a conflict between self. and respond_to, or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `respond_to` is an instance method but `get_details` declared as a class method `self.get_details` - did you try to make `get_details` an instance method by removing `self.`?

Comment: IMHO your naming convention might lead to many typos once other developers will work on the same project. Why `Teamember` instead of `TeamMember` or `teamate` instead of `team_mate`?